# Allowing changing location perl modules are loaded from with configuration argument

Tags: perl, configuration, module

I currently have a mess of Perl code that includes something like a configuration.pm file that exports a large number of variables that other modules are using.  The same module uses at least one module, call it Foo, which we wrote in some of the helper methods provided by the configuration.pm (they should be in a different module, but not ready to change this yet).

Currently it loads the module with something like this right near the top of the file:

```
Begin{ push @INC, 'hard/coded/directory'}
use Module::Foo;
```

I'm trying to get rid of this hard coded directory.  I've already added a default configuration file for it to read data from.  I moved the import down some and replaced the use with a require, something like this...

```
$script_directory = $config_data_from_file{'script_directory'};
push @inc, $script_directory;
require Module::Foo;
```

However, I want to add a  command line argument to Main.pl to point to a different configuration file if I don't want to use the default one.  My problem is that all the other modules expect configuration.pm to have loaded configuration data and required foo as soon as they include it.  So I can't have configuration.pm wait to initialize until main.pl is ready.  The closest I can come up with is something like this:

```
package Configuration;

load_config_file('default/file/location');

sub load_config_file($){

   $config_data_from_file = read_file(@_[0]);

   $script_directory = $config_data_from_file{'script_directory'};
   push @inc, $script_directory;
   require Module::Foo;

  #load the rest
}
```

and have Main.pl recall the load_config_file if a command line option changes the configuration file.

But this is a problem for two reasons.  First, if my default script location doesn't exist I still explode when I try to do the first import.  Second, I'm requiring Foo twice, overwriting it, which could lead to issues if there are difference between the files.  For that matter adding the default script_directory to @INC should be avoided.

There are a few ways to fix the problem I could see.  A way to more cleanly load different versions of a module to replace the old one, a way to make Foo delay it's attempt to load until the first time it's used in the file, or a way to delay the $load_config_file method until after I read the configuration file for example.  However, as a perl newbie I don't know how to do any of them, and haven't had much luck finding out how online.

I actually can do this now, with a fragile order of loading data that makes presumptions or by skipping ahead to a more through refactor of dozens of scripts to implement the long term solution sooner (but I'm really afraid to touch that much code before I have a way to test the code on my computer).  However, I'm asking partially in hopes of learning more features of Perl I may find useful later; how would this be solved if I couldn't do the refactoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to give the configuration file as the first parameter you can do something like this:

Main script:

```
  #!perl

  BEGIN {
    use Configuration;
  }

  use Module::Foo;
  ... rest of script ...
```

Configuration.pm:

```
  package Configuration;

  load_config_file($ARGV[0] || 'default/file/location');

  sub load_config_file($){

     $config_data_from_file = read_file(@_[0]);

     $script_directory = $config_data_from_file;
     push @INC, $script_directory;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution in general was to look for my -f argument for a configuration file in my configuration.pm as soon as it is loaded and load the configuration file if possible then, while leaving the @ARGV variable untouched so that others could still parse it.  This means we end up parsing command line args twice (actually 3 times), but that doesn't do any real harm.  I am enforcing the -f argument being predefined in any module that uses my configuration.pm, and sort of require configuration.pm to be the very first module we include, but I consider that a minor expense.  Anyone using our configuration.pm file for configuration arguments should desire that behavior.

I found AppConfig was the best module for handling this.  My solution could be done without it, but AppConfig made it cleaner because it combined means of loading variables from config file and command line.  in fact I, by pure accident, ended up adding the ability to modify any single variable directly from the command line if they choose the way I did it.

My configuration.pm looks something like hits (rewriting this from memory, not exact)

```
$conf = AppConfig -> new({ 
          GLOBAL=> {
                EXPAND => AppConfig::Expand_Var,
                ARGCOUNT => AppConfig::ARGCOUNT_ONE
        }})

$conf.define("script_dir", {DEFAULT = "/default/location"});
$conf->define("f", {ALIAS ="file|conf_file"});
...other defines here

#read config file if -f arg exists
parse_commandline_args();
$conf->file($conf->conf_file()) if defined $conf->conf_file()

#reread command line so that arguments on it override those in conf file
parse_commandline_args();

#at this point script_dir should be correct so safely include it.
push @INC $conf->script_dir();

sub parse_commandline_args(){

   $copy_of_args = [@ARGV];
   $conf->args($copy_of_args);
}
```

My main.pl is practically untouched.  I use configuration.pm near the top of the module and everything else just works.  I still need to go through and redefine all the scripts that Use a script to require it instead so that configuration.pm has time to update the INC before it runs, but other then that the rest just works.  Anywhere I want to use content from the configuration file I now just can $conf->variable()

The parse_commandline_args is important.  just using $conf->args() will erase the content of @ARGV, making them unavailable for later modules, like my main.pl.  By copying the array first we leave the original @ARGV untouched for later use.

Not sure if I would recommend this from scratch, feels wrong the way configuration.pm is automagically doing everything, but for updating our ugly prototype to function long enough to maintain it until were funded to write the *proper* version, which I will not be doing in perl, it will do.